# program for loan amount and loan period

Tags: python

Write a program that lets the user enter the loan amount and loan period in number of years and displays the monthly and total payments for each interest rate starting from 3% to 5%, with an increment of 1/8.  The formula of calculating the monthly payment and total payment are as follows:

I need help with the increment of 1/8. I've thought of a for loop but Python does not allow floats. I researched a bit and found something called numpy,  but I haven't learned that yet. Is there a way to do it?

Here is what I have so far:

```
monthlyPay = 0
total = 0

#Prompt the user to enter loan amount and loan period in years
loanAmount = float(input("Enter loan amount: $"))
years = int(input("Enter loan period in years: "))                  

#Display Table Header
print("Interest\tMonthly Pay\tTotal")

#Display Table Results
for yr in range(0,years):
    interestRate = 3/(100*12)

    #Calculate Monthly Payment
    monthlyPay = loanAmount*interestRate/(1-(1/((1+interestRate)**(years*12))))

    #Calculate Total Payment
    total = monthlyPay * years * 12
    print(format(interestRate, '.3f'), '%\t\t', format(monthlyPay, '.2f'),\
          '\t\t', format(total, '.2f'), sep = '')
```

Comment: Python allows floats, it just does not default to float all of the time.  For instance, this line here: `interestRate = 3/(100*12)` will do integer division in Python 2 leaving you with `interestRate = 0`.  To ensure that float math is used you can add a decimal at the end of one of your number constants, such as: `3/(100*12.)`

Comment: I would say increment an integer by one, and then divide it by 8 within the for loop.  Otherwise, if you're looking into numpy, checkout [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to calculate the values you need, but from what I understand is that you need the interest rate to be starting with 3% and increase every year with 1/8, which is 0.125, and stops at five. If this is the case, `numPy` would be helpful. You could make `interestRate` as an array like this:

```
import numpy as np
interestRate = np.arange(3, 3 + 0.125*years, 0.125).clip(max=5)
```

[`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) gives an array of your need and [`clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) makes all the values above 5 be equal to 5.